# How do you get gallery(and associated image viewers) to acknowledge the existence of a new image?

Tags: android, android-gallery

In my app I save the text of the webview as an image file and start a share function to allow the user to share the file, the image is also saved in the pictures folder. I can confirm that they do appear in the pictures folder via file browsers but Gallery is not updated.

The code I used to take the image is

```
   private void htmlCapture2() {
    if (!checksd()) {
        Log.e("sdcard", "failed sd card check");
        //we dont have permision so lets not continue
        return;
    }
    if (!checkFolder()) {
        Log.e("folder", "failed folder check");
        //we dont have a folder so lets not continue
        return;
    }
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = screenshot(webView);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/png");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,"title");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/png");
    Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
    OutputStream outstream;
    try {
        outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outstream);
        outstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    share.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share Image"));
}

public static Bitmap screenshot(WebView webView) {
    try {
        //float scale = webView.getScaleX();
        int height;
        height = webView.getHeight();

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(0xffffffff);
        webView.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

It took me three days to get this far, and even more searching for a solution to the latest issue.
I know I need to use MediaScannerConnection but it needs a file name and I do not have one as I do not really create a File.
I have seen solutions that say to scan the sd card, but this seems a bad idea and when I tried them out of desperation they do not seem to work with the latest SDKs

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I never use `insert()` for this, as it's not particularly well-documented what `MediaStore` is going to do here. I suggest that you write the image to a file, then follow the `MediaScannerConnection` recipe.

Comment: I was told using mediastore this way was the recommended route, however by going the file route and saving the image it has fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform android MediaStore that a new image has been added and you can do that by the following

```
public Uri addImageToMediaStore(ContentResolver mresolver, String imgType, File filepath) {
    ContentValues Cvalues = new ContentValues();
    Cvalues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "player");
    Cvalues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "player");
    Cvalues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "");
    Cvalues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/" + imgType);
    Cvalues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    Cvalues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    Cvalues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filepath.toString());
    return mresolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Cvalues);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The issue is getting the filepath, since we are not creating a File we never actually have a filepath, thats all handled by the insert()
unless i have missed something which is possible been staring at this issue for a few days

Answer (score 0):

After a suggestion from CommonsWare, i went to the file saving method (i know its not the recommended method, but it does have the luxury of working)

```
   private void htmlCapture2() {
    if (!checksd()) {
        Log.e("sdcard", "failed sd card check");
        //we dont have permision so lets not continue
        return;
    }
    if (!checkFolder()) {
        Log.e("folder", "failed folder check");
        //we dont have a folder so lets not continue
        return;
    }
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = screenshot(webView);
    String filename = "capture_" + z.getCurrentTimeStamp() + ".png";
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "", filename);

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/png");
    //ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,"title");
    //values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/png");
    //Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);


    OutputStream outstream;
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        Log.i("ExternalStorage","I think the path is : "+file.toString());
        ostream.close();
        Log.i("ExternalStorage","I think the path is : "+file.toString());
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });
        //outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        //bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outstream);
        //outstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    //share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    share.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share Image"));
}
```

I have some tidying up on it to do of course, and the image does not appear in gallery per-say, though if you go to downloads album in gallery it is there which is an improvement on before.